# How to rotate element of an array in top to bottom fashion in every iteration

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have an array of n size 
suppose my original array is:

```
array=(alpha,bravo,charlie,delta,echo,foxtrot);
```

and i want to rotate the above array in leftward 
ex output 1st iteration

```
array=(bravo,charlie,delta,echo,foxtrot,alpha);
```

and 2nd iteration

```
array=(charlie,delta,echo,foxtrot,alpha,bravo);
```

and i want to do this in every iteration till original array is achieved.

Note :The above array i am getting from MySQL output for a specific query. So the original array will be always `array=(alpha,bravo,charlie,delta,echo,foxtrot);`

Thanks in Advance for any suggestion and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array('alpha','bravo','charlie','delta','echo','foxtrot');

for($i=0; $i< count($array);$i++)
{
    $firstValue = array_shift($array);
    array_push($array, $firstValue);
    var_dump($array); //here you get your array with the first value shifted to the end of the array
}
```

Result:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "bravo"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "charlie"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "delta"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "echo"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "foxtrot"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "alpha"
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "charlie"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "delta"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "echo"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "foxtrot"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "alpha"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "bravo"
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "delta"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "echo"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "foxtrot"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "alpha"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "bravo"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "charlie"
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "echo"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "foxtrot"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "alpha"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "bravo"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "charlie"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "delta"
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "foxtrot"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "alpha"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "bravo"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "charlie"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "delta"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "echo"
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "alpha"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "bravo"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "charlie"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "delta"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "echo"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "foxtrot"
}
```